# COBOL ERASE sentence

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I'm watching COBOL tutorials, they use the "erase" statement to clean the screen and it doesn't work for me. The compiler indicates "syntax error, unexpected ERASE"

The code is:

```
DISPLAY "1.- CALC, 2.- CLOSE" ERASE.
```

It is my mistake?

I am using opencobol on ubuntu
Sorry about my English, it's not my native language

Comment: The sentence here is `DISPLAY`. `ERASE` here is not a sentence but at best a clause, and a non-standard one. If your Cobol implementation doesn't support it, this is what you will get.

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes please mark as answer, if not comment.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by @user207421 `ERASE` is not a statement, it is a clause for the `DISPLAY` statement, and it even is standardized - but (standard-wise) it needs a specification what you want to erase:

```
ERASE [END] [OF] LINE
      [END] [OF] SCREEN
      EOL
      EOS
```

The syntax you have shown is actually the *very* non-standard, outdated Microsoft-COBOL `DISPLAY` statement with [`ERASE phrase`](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/vc60/DevHub/HRLHLHDMSO01U910.html).

If you still use open-cobol then the package is heavily outdated, there should be a new gnucobol package available in Ubuntu (otherwise you could build from source). Using GnuCOBOL 2.2 you get a nicer error message:

> error: syntax error, unexpected ., expecting LINE or SCREEN

And then you can decide if you want the old ms-cobol variant (that's supported in GnuCOBOL, but only with the pos-specifier) or the standard variant (`ERASE EOS` would be the compatible version and is supported by many compilers).